# Understanding proof in Markov Chains and Mixing Times

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Kindly help me to understand the proof of Lemma 4.10 from "Markov Chains and Mixing Times" (https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf).

The goal ist to prove $d(t) \le \bar{d}(t)$, with

$d(t) := \max\limits_{x \in S} \Vert P^t(x, \cdot) - \pi \Vert_{TV}$ and $\bar d(t):= \max\limits_{x,y \in S} \Vert P^t(x, \cdot) - P^t(y, \cdot) \Vert_{TV}$ and $P$ being the transition matrix and $S$ the state space and $\pi$ the stationary distribution of a Markov chain.

The proof starts with a reminder of the definition of the stationary distribution $\pi$,

$\pi(A) = \sum\limits_{y \in S}\pi(y)P^t(y,A)$.

Then the first equation says:

$P^t(x,A) - \pi(A) = \sum\limits_{y \in S} \pi(y) \big( P^t(x,A)-P^t(y,A) \big)$.

I understand that we can fill in the definition of $\pi(A)$ in $P^t(x,A) - \pi(A)$ what gives us

$P^t(x,A) - \pi(A) = P^t(x,A) - \sum\limits_{y \in S}\pi(y)P^t(y,A)$.

But I fail to see why I can multiple $P^t(x,A)$ with $\pi(y)$, sum over all $y \in S$ and then use the distriutive law to end up with $\sum\limits_{y \in S} \pi(y) \big( P^t(x,A)-P^t(y,A) \big)$.

I'm sure I just miss one step but would appreciate your feedback!

Comment: You mean the step you don't understand is why $P^t(x,A) - \sum_{y \in S} \pi(y) P^t(y,A) = \sum_{y \in S} \pi(y)(P^t(x,A) - P^t(y,A))$? This just works because $P^t(x,A)$ doesn't depend on $y$ so it can be pulled out of the sum of that term, and then of course the sum of $\pi(y)$ is $1$. I can make this an answer if you clarify whether it suffices for you.

Comment: @Ian: I must have been blind and feel ashamed having asked as it turned out to be so trivial! Kindly mark your reply as an answer and accept my gratitude!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the step you don't understand is why $P^t(x,A) - \sum_{y \in S} \pi(y) P^t(y,A) = \sum_{y \in S} \pi(y)(P^t(x,A) - P^t(y,A))$? This just works because $P^t(x,A)$ doesn't depend on $y$ so it can be pulled out of the sum of that term, and then of course the sum of $\pi(y)$ is $1$.